# How to add sound on alert pop up?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I developing a system in php-mysql and I am using sweetalert.min.js to get alerts.. but along with it I need to add notification tone as alert pop-ups. Below is the code

```
if(((sms_alert == 'NULL') && (email_alert == 'NULL')))
                    {
                       swal("You have " + obj[i].e_name + " event at this moment");
                    }
```

Please help me out whether it is done with javascript, jquery or some other thing.. n how is it achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using JQuery

https://github.com/admsev/jquery-play-sound

$.playSound('http://example.org/sound.mp3');

Answer (score 0):

simply add alert tone and call it on the event prior you call the alert, below is the way you achieve it..

```
$('<audio id="chatAudio"><source src="webim/sounds/notify.ogg" type="audio/ogg"><source src="webim/sounds/notify.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><source src="webim/sounds/notify.wav" type="audio/wav"></audio>').appendTo('body');
 $('#chatAudio')[0].play();
```